# Oracle get current Year & Previous Year and coming year from select query

Tags: sql, oracle

What i am doing is i am getting data from a table and i want few more columns from sysdate not sure how to get ..

Example

```
Select id,  extract(year from sysdate) as currentyear ,   extract(year from sysdate) Previous_Year ,
extract(year from sysdate) Upcoming Year from testtable
```

so the result should be

```
id   current-year   Previous_Year   Upcoming 

   1       2019         2018           2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have Oracle accessible to test but might try:

```
Select id,  extract(year from sysdate) as currentyear ,   extract(year from sysdate)-1 Previous_Year ,
extract(year from sysdate)+1 Upcoming Year from testtable
```

Comment: Thanks :)  @nicholas